# difference between setValue and push method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone please help me elaborate difference between setValue() and push() methods in Firebase? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @RaajNadar Nope thats not a duplicate. This question is about the difference between push() and set() and you duplicate is about update() and set().

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data read this page

Comment: Why did they mark it as duplicate?! It's totally not! I gave you +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SetValue() is to write or replace data in a defined path. Example : I want to set the username for a given user :

```
Firebase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child("username").setValue("Jhon Doe");
```

SetValue() can also be used to delete data in a defined path by calling it without parameters:

```
Firebase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child("username").setValue();
```

Push(), is used to add a new node. So, every time this method is called, firebase will automatically generate a new unique ID. Calling Push() without parameters won't actually create any data in the database but only generate the unique ID (on the client side).

Comment: Do you mind if i add some extra information to your answer?

Comment: Feel free to suggest anything you judge useful :)

Comment: If this helped you, please mark as answered so other people can find it easily. Thank you.